# PD model for CDGA over the integers

Tags: rational-homotopy-theory

Lambrechts and Stanley constructed Poincaré duality model for cdga over a field with simply connected cohomology. Are there construction of PD model for CDGA over integer coefficients?

Comment: What's a PD model?

Comment: CDGA with Poincare duality.